# Building Tensorflow r1.12 with Cuda 10 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I really have tried getting built. I have followed the instructions [here](https://www.python36.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-10-0-for-python-on-ubuntu/) and [here](https://medium.com/@vitali.usau/install-cuda-10-0-cudnn-7-3-and-build-tensorflow-gpu-from-source-on-ubuntu-18-04-3daf720b83fe) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source). Clean system:

- Ubuntu 18.04 server
- Ubuntu Gnome
- Cuda 10.0
- cuDNN 7.4.1
- NCCL 2.3.7
- TensorRT 5.0.2.1
- Tensorflow r1.12
- Python 3.6
- GCC 7.3.0
  using the command line:

  bazel build --config=cuda --config=mkl //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

This is the error:

```
WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
/devel/software/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=171
ERROR: Config value cuda is not defined in any .rc file
```

Anybody know which parts of bazel.rc the need to be imported?

Why is cuda not defined?

If I try:

bazel test -c opt -- //tensorflow/... -//tensorflow/compiler/... -//tensorflow/contrib/lite/...

It fails with this error:

ERROR: /devel/software/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:3768:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/python:_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' failed (Exit 1) gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -shared -o bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so -Wl,--version-script bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal_versionscript.lds ... (remaining 65 argument(s) skipped)

Anyone had success? (Obviously at least 2 people have) Maybe someone could tell me what I am doing wrong? Or how to get this built?

Comment: Some success. I know this is not Windows but a reboot helped.  Fails now with this error:
ERROR: /devel/software/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:592:1: Executing genrule //tensorflow:tensorflow_python_api_gen failed (Exit 1) bash failed: error executing command /bin/bash -c ... (remaining 1 argument(s) skipped)

Cannot use --config=cuda and cannot use --config=mkl Anyone know why?

Comment: The original error "ERROR: Config value cuda is not defined in any .rc file", is an error only seen if using Bazel 0.19.0, try using Bazel 0.18.0 to build. And I would remove the --config=mkl, since you want the operations to be done on the gpu.

Comment: @William D. Irons - Thank you! That was the answer. Very much obliged.

Doug

Answer (score 3):

Do as what is said in the warning and it will work.

```
"WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
/devel/software/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc"
```

You should have a file .bazelrc at  /devel/software/tensorflow/.bazelrc. At the top of this file add the following code snippet.

```
import /devel/software/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc
```

Enjoy!